# routing not happening in react router version 4

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I may have done silly mistake this time but I am but getting it what. I started with react router v4 but my routing is not happening. I try to hit url manually as well as by button click no result. here's my route config. and FYI I am using LinkContaier to redirection

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './stores/configureStores';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import HeaderContainer from "./containers/HeaderContainer"
import ProgramProfileContainer from "./containers/ProgramProfileContainer"
const store = configureStore();


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
     <BrowserRouter >
      <Switch>
        <HeaderContainer/>
        {/* <Route exact path="/" component={HeaderContainer}/> */}
          <Route path="program-profile/:program_id" component={ProgramProfileContainer}/>   
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

this is my container

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default class ProgramProfileContainer extends React.Component{

    render(){
        console.log("program profile")
        return(
            <h1> this is profile </h1>
        )
    }
}
```

i hit the url like program-profile/3 but rendered nothing no error in console also

Comment: Try adding a forward slash `path="/program-profile/:program_id"` and it should work on button click and also manually if in webpack you set devServer historyAPIFallback: true

Comment: I am using react scripts so it has in built config and this dint work..:(

Comment: Remove `<Switch>`

Comment: I am using LinkContainer does it make any difference?

Comment: @Fawaz: router can have only one child elemednt

Comment: @LowCool Router can have many child elements. That won't be an issue.

Comment: @Fawaz: I got error saying that

Comment: @LowCool Replace `<Switch>` with `<div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use switch inside browser router :

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter >
        <div>
           <Route exact path="/" component={HeaderContainer}/>
           <Route path="/program-profile/:program_id" component={ProgramProfileContainer}/>   
       </div>
     </BrowserRouter>
 </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Why would you suggest to not use a switch component

Comment: Switch is also a router. You should use only one router based on requirements. Refer here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems to be OK. But this is how I do it normally:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import promise from 'redux-promise';

import reducers from './reducers';
import ProgramProfileContainer from "./containers/ProgramProfileContainer"

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="program-profile/:program_id" component={ProgramProfileContainer} />
            <Route path="/" component={IndexPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

When you use `Link` it should be like this:

```
<Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>
  {post.title}
</Link>
```